# Generating consistent arrays of datenums

Tags: matlab

Whenever I need to plot data vs time I generate the corresponding array of `datenums` so I can visualize a timeline on the `plot` by calling `datetick`.

Let's suppose I need all the datenums with a 1 minute interval between hours `h_1` and `h_2`. This is how would I generate my array of datenums `vd`:

```
h_1 = [01 00]; % 01:00 AM
h_2 = [17 00]; % 17:00 PM

HH_1 = h_1(1); % Hour digits of h_1
MM_1 = h_1(2); % Minute digits of h_1

HH_2 = h_2(1); % Hour digits of h_2
MM_2 = h_2(2); % Minute digits of h_2


% Vector of 01:00 - 17:30 with 1 minute increments (24 hours a day, 1440 minutes a day)

vd = HH_1/24+MM_1/1440:1/1440:HH_2/24+MM_2/1440;
```

I learnt this technique reading [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7423-create-time-intervals-of-a-time-vector#answer_10210).

On the other hand, whenever I wish to generate a single datenum, I use the `datenum` function like this:

```
d = datenum('14:20','HH:MM');
```

Since 14:20 is comprised between the interval 01:00 - 17:30, its datenum should be too! Unfortunately this is not working as expected, since the number assigned to `d` is radically different to those values contained in `vd`. I think I might be missing something, probably something to do with setting up a reference date or similar.

So what would be the appropriate way to generate datenums consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the datenum function gives you a number of days from January 0, 0000. 
So when calling

```
d = datenum('14:20','HH:MM');
```

you get a number about 735965, while the numbers in your vd array are between 0 and 1. In order to substruct the days between January 0, 0000 and today you can write

```
d = datenum('14:20','HH:MM') - datenum('00:00','HH:MM');
```

Then your code will look like

```
h_1 = [01 00]; % 01:00 AM
h_2 = [17 00]; % 17:00 PM

HH_1 = h_1(1); % Hour digits of h_1
MM_1 = h_1(2); % Minute digits of h_1

HH_2 = h_2(1); % Hour digits of h_2
MM_2 = h_2(2); % Minute digits of h_2

vd = HH_1/24 + MM_1/1440   :  1/1440  :  HH_2/24+MM_2/1440;

d = datenum('14:20','HH:MM') - datenum('00:00','HH:MM');

display(d);
display(vd(801));
```

And the result:

```
d = 0.5972
ans = 0.5972
```