# Convert milliseconds into hours and plot

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to convert an array of milliseconds and its respective data. However I want to do so in hours and minutes.

```
Millis = [60000 120000 180000 240000....]
Power = [ 12 14 12 13 14 ...]
```

I've set it up so the data records every minute, hence the 60000 `millis` (= 1 minimte). I am trying to plot time on the `x` axis and power on the `y`. I would like to have the `x` axis displayed in hours and minutes with each respective power data corresponding to its respective time.

I've tried this

```
for i=2:length(Millis)
Conv2Min(i) = Millis(i) / 60000;
Time(i) = startTime + Conv2Min(i);
if (Time(i-1) > Time(i) + 60)
Time(i) + 100;
end

end
s = num2str(Time);
```

This in attempt to turn the milliseconds into hours starting at 08:00 and once 60 minutes have past going to 09:00, the problem is plotting this. I get a gap between 08:59 and 09:00. I also cannot maintain the `0=initial 0`.

Comment: Please not that in English only names and the word I go with capitals (and the first word of a sentence, obviously), so exactly the other way around from what you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this scenario it is preferable to work with [`datenum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) values and then use [`datetick`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to set the format of the tick labels of your `plot` to `'HH:MM'`.

Let's suppose that you started taking measurements at `t_1 = [HH_1, MM_1]` and stopped taking measurements at `t_2 = [HH_2, MM_2]`.

A cool trick to generate the array of `datenum` values is to use the following expression:

```
time_datenums = HH_1/24 + MM_1/1440 : 1/1440 : HH_2/24 + MM_2/1440;
```

Explanation:

We are creating a regularly-spaced vector `time_datenums = A:B:C` using the [`colon (:) operator`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), where `A` is the starting `datenum` value, `B` is the increment between `datenum` values and `C` is the ending `datenum` value.

Since your measurements have been taken every minute (60000 milliseconds), then the increment between `datenum` values should be of 1 minute too. As a day has 24 hours, that makes 1440 minutes a day, so use `B = 1/1440` as the increment between vector elements, to get 1 minute increments.

For `A` and `C` we simply need to divide the hour digits by 24 and the minute digits by 1440 and sum them up like this:

- `A = HH_1/24 + MM_1/1440`
- `C = HH_2/24 + MM_2/1440`

So for example, if `t_1 = [08, 00]`, then `A = 08/24 + 00/1440`. As simple as that.

Notice that this procedure doesn't use the [`datenum` function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) at all, and still, it manages to generate a valid array of `datenum` values only taking into consideration the time of the `datenum`, without needing to bother about the date of the `datenum`. You can learn more about this [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7423-create-time-intervals-of-a-time-vector#answer_10210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33978435/3599179).

---

Going back to your original problem, let's have a look at the code:

```
time_millisec = 0:60000:9e6;             % Time array in milliseconds.
power = 10*rand(size(time_millisec));    % Random power data.

% Elapsed time in milliseconds.
elapsed_millisec = time_millisec(end) - time_millisec(1); 
% Integer part of elapsed hours.
elapsed_hours_int = fix(elapsed_millisec/(1000*60*60));
% Fractional part of elapsed hours.
elapsed_hours_frac = (elapsed_millisec/(1000*60*60)) - elapsed_hours_int;

t_1 = [08, 00]; % Start time 08:00
t_2 = [t_1(1) + elapsed_hours_int, t_1(2) + elapsed_hours_frac*60]; % Compute End time.

HH_1 = t_1(1); % Hour digits of t_1
MM_1 = t_1(2); % Minute digits of t_1

HH_2 = t_2(1); % Hour digits of t_2
MM_2 = t_2(2); % Minute digits of t_2

time_datenums = HH_1/24+MM_1/1440:1/1440:HH_2/24+MM_2/1440; % Array of datenums.

plot(time_datenums, power);    % Plot data.
datetick('x', 'HH:MM');        % Set 'HH:MM' datetick format for the x axis.
```

This is the output:

[image: plot with dateticks in 'HH:MM? format]

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you can use datenum itself to convert a Mx6 matrix into datenums. No need to construct them yourself. The seconds automatically overflow to minutes, hours, days.

Comment: @Gelliant Please, do read my answer and understand that my approach is very different from yours. Thanks for your contribution. Cheers.

Comment: yes I see. You added a bit at the top. The approach is a bit different, but not in line with the question asked. He has an array of millisecond timings, you take the first and last and construct a datenum array.

Comment: @Gelliant Sorry to disagree. This approach is totally valid, since OP is taking measurements every minute on a regular basis: *"I've set it up so the data records every minute"*. So the time array in this problem grows at a constant rate of 60000 milliseconds, and thus using the start time and the elapsed time is more than enough. By the way, the `time` array in my code is an array of millisecond timings, just in case you missed it.

Comment: If you replace in my answer d = [2017 05 01 08 00 00];  with d = [0 0 0 8 0 0]; you would generate the exact same datenums with my code. Sorry to disagree indeed, I really don't see the big difference in our methods, and don't see any advantage of using yours.

Comment: @Gelliant The big difference is that I'm generating the datenum values manually without even using the `datenum` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143095/discussion-between-gelliant-and-codeaviator).

Comment: Thanks a heap that's exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use datenums:

```
Millis = [60000 120000 180000 240000 360000];
Power = [ 12 14 12 13 14 ];
d = [2017 05 01 08 00 00]; %starting point (y,m,d,h,m,s)
d = repmat(d,[length(Millis),1]);
d(:,6)=Millis/1000; %add them as seconds
D=datenum(d); %convert to datenums
plot(D,Power) %plot
datetick('x','HH:MM') %set the x-axis to datenums with HH:MM as format
```

an even shorter approach would be: (thanks to codeaviator for the idea)

```
Millis = [60000 120000 180000 240000 360000];
Power = [ 12 14 12 13 14 ];
D = 8/24+Millis/86400000; %24h / day, 86400000ms / day
plot(D,Power) %plot
datetick('x','HH:MM') %set the x-axis to datenums with HH:MM as format
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is an easier way using `datetick` and `datenum`, but I couldn't figure it out. This should solve your problem for now:

```
Millis=6e4:6e4:6e6;
power=randi([5 15],1,numel(Millis));
hours=floor(Millis/(6e4*60))+8; minutes=mod(Millis,(6e4*60))/6e4; % Calculate the hours and minutes of your Millisecond vector.
plot(Millis,power)
xlabels=arrayfun(@(x,y) sprintf('%d:%d',x,y),hours,minutes,'UniformOutput',0); % Create time-strings of the format HH:MM for your XTickLabels
tickDist=10; % define how often you want your XTicks (e.g. 1 if you want the ticks every minute)
set(gca,'XTick',Millis(tickDist:tickDist:end),'XTickLabel',xlabels(tickDist:tickDist:end))
```